# Restoring dropped collections from mongodb without taking dump?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have dropped few collections from my mongo database [version 2.6] using db.collection.drop() command. I haven't backed up or created dump before dropping [it is an unfortunate mistake]. I just wanna know if there is any way to restore those dropped collections in this scenario.

I was hoping there may be a way as mongoDb won't be freeing up the space by default even after dropping collections.

Any insights into this would be of great help.

Comment: Are you using oplog for your database ?

Comment: @mickl I am afraid not :(